# How can I get a detailed error message from NSDictionary writeToURL?

Tags: swift, cocoa, error-handling, nsdictionary

I extended an application with simple import/export functionality which is using plist files to store the exported objects. To save the objects I use a `NSDictionary` and the `writeToURL` method (sandboxed app).

The relevant portion of the code looks like this:

```
savePanel.beginSheetModalForWindow(self.view.window!) { (result) in
    savePanel.orderOut(nil)
    if result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton {
        let saveURL = savePanel.URL!
        let values = NSMutableDictionary()
        for propertyDescription in selectedEvent.entity.properties {
            let propertyName = propertyDescription.name
            values[propertyName] = selectedEvent.valueForKey(propertyName)
        }
        if !values.writeToURL(saveURL, atomically: true) {
            // error handling?
        }
    }
}
```

Now I wondered **if there is a way to get a detailed error message** if saving the file failed?

Comment: `writeToFile` only returns a Bool https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/writeToFile:atomically:

Comment: @EricD I am fully aware of this. Therefore my question: is there a way how to get a detailed error message if this method fails?

Comment: you can use NSData method `func writeToURL(url: NSURL, options writeOptionsMask: NSDataWritingOptions) throws` if you would like to handle the error

Comment: @LeoDabus I found no method to get a `NSData` object with the plist from the `NSDictionary`. How could I do this conversion?

Answer (score 0):

I did not realise the answer is quite simple. Instead of using the helper method on the `NSDictionary` there is the `NSPropertyListSerialization` which provides the full set of methods to serialize an deserialize plists.

Using this class, a `NSData` object is created and this object is written to the disk. Writing a `NSData` object provides all required error handling.

Here the code example from above with the new implementation:

```
savePanel.beginSheetModalForWindow(self.view.window!) { (result) in
    savePanel.orderOut(nil)
    if result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton {
        let saveURL = savePanel.URL!
        let values = NSMutableDictionary()
        for propertyDescription in selectedEvent.entity.properties {
            let propertyName = propertyDescription.name
            values[propertyName] = selectedEvent.valueForKey(propertyName)
        }
        do {
            let data = try NSPropertyListSerialization.dataWithPropertyList(values, format: .XMLFormat_v1_0, options: NSPropertyListWriteOptions())
            try data.writeToURL(saveURL, options: [.DataWritingAtomic])
        } catch let error as NSError {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.view.window!.presentError(error)
            }
        } catch {
            let unknownError = NSError(domain: kAppErrorDomain, code: 201, userInfo: [
                NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Unknown error while writing the export file."
            ])
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.view.window!.presentError(unknownError)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @LeoDabus You are right, in my special case I can guarantee the dictionary will always serialise without problem. Nevertheless I will adjust the example code.